# Wordpress I18n generator: Missing Keys

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

I downloaded the I18n generator package from: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Generating_a_POT_file. I want to generate a pot file for my created template now:

```
php makepot.php  /home/mr/workspace/blog/wp-content/themes/myTheme/ de_DE.pot
```

After executing this command, I get a de_DE.pot with some the WP standard keys in. But my new keys will not be found. But if I add them to the file manually and upload it, they will be translated.
Why doesn't WordPress pick up all my keys?

Comment: Just a side note - can you try using the [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/) plugin to generate the .pot file? I've always used this plugin and it works perfectly for both themes and plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the poEdit in the following way.

1. File Menu > New Catalog
2. Set the language as per your need. Set utf8
3. Set the paths as . and ..(if you want to place your .mo file at languages folder).
4. Define the functions from which the strings to take( ie *, _*, _e, _n, _x, _ex etc).
5. Now save the file to your template's folder as templateName.po
6. Now update catalog.
7. Upon saving the .mo file will be generated in the same folder.
8. Now rename the .mo file to the specific Locale (for mine bn_BD.mo, for your case de_DE.mo)

I would suggest a few tips from [here](http://www.solostream.com/blog/tutorials/translate-wordpress-theme/)

Comment: Check this [post](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/16-vital-checks-before-releasing-a-wordpress-theme/) and [this](http://urbangiraffe.com/articles/translating-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/) for more information.

Comment: Please explain how you wanted it to be.

Comment: like you see it on the top. I wanted to get support for a php script, and not use poEdit^^

Comment: Well, there's even some wordpress plugins which does the job of poEdit. But poEdit does it better. There are also php and other scripts which works with gettext parser for fetching the localized strings in a folder.

If you read the articles I provided you are likely to get acquainted with the settings a pot file is made with. While creating po/pot on poEdit you have seen I stated on step four that you specify which functions should be read. And on step 3 which folders to fetch from. Those are the gettext parameters by which all the strings are fetched.